# Why does SpaCy no longer have wheels for version<2.0.0 on Pypi?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, pypi, python-wheel

I need a wheel for SpaCy to fix my build issue. Where can I find it? The file name is supposed to be `spacy-1.10.1-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl`

They did have wheels before. I was using a 1.9.0 wheel but I need to upgrade it to 1.10.1 and I was not able to find one.

Comment: What is the build issue you're experiencing? This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 2):

The `SpaCy` project did not start publishing wheels for their releases until version 2.0.13.